# Simple Macro does two times in a row

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a Macro to take a value from a table and ''paste'' it in a cell in Excel. The problem is that the macro does not work twice in a row, it works the first time, but when i run it again, nothing happens.

For instance, when I run it the first time, it assign ''2019'' in the cell ''BT11''. When I delete what's in the cell ''BT11'' and run the macro again, it leave the cell blank.

Thanks for your help!

Here's the code;

```
Sub Macro4()

Dim Table As Integer

Table = Empty

Table = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau27").DataBodyRange(1, 1).Value

Range("BT11") = Table

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note, but remove the `Table = Empty`.

Comment: I just removed it... still not working.. thanks

Comment: Highly suggest that 1) you use a `Worksheet` reference instead of `ActiveSheet`, and 2) that you qualify which worksheet/workbook the `Range("BT11")` is in/on.... also be explicit, `Range("BT11").Value = Table`.

Comment: I found the problem... I got rid of the variable ''Table'' since it was useless... It's working fine now... Thanks for your help @BigBen